# List view not showing up items in few devices and emulators

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview which is populated from a custom adapter. The xml of the list is:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
```

And I use the following code to get the view for the list

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    EntryItem temp;
    TextView tvEntry,tvDate;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entrylayout , parent, false);
    }
    tvEntry=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEntry);
    tvDate=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    temp=(EntryItem)getItem(position);
    tvEntry.setText(temp.getEntry());
    tvDate.setText(temp.getEntryDate());
    return convertView;
}
```

This is how I bind adapter:

```
//I get the values from another activity into main activity through a bundle
//I then load them into adapter
myAdapter.addEntry(bundle.getString("name"), bundle.getString("date"));
```

I do this onCreate:

```
entryList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
entryList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Entry Item is a class which defines the structure of items in the list. I bind the adapter using an arraylist of that class. The problem is this work fine in my emulator and few devices, but fails in few others. I used log.d where the entry is added into adapter, the values get displayed. There are no exceptions thrown either. Any idea what else might be the mistake ?

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar issue. Did you eventually solved it? If so, please tell me how.